# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '../output/kaggle/working/train'

Tags: python, classification, kaggle, multiclass-classification

i was trying to generate image dataset from images folder , first i copied the trained and validation dataset in separate folders train and validation respectively in /output/kaggle/working, then  i tried to generate image data set from this folders and i got this error.FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '../output/kaggle/working/train'.

i tried this code :

```
data_dir='../output/kaggle/working/train'
img_height,img_width=180,180
batch_size=32
train_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
  data_dir,
  subset="training",
  seed=123,
  validation_split=0.2,
  label_mode="categorical",
  image_size=(img_height, img_width),
  batch_size=batch_size)
```

and i was expecting to generate a dataset from this images folder.

Comment: Does that directory exist? You could `import sys; print(sys.getcwd())` to see the root of your relative path.

Comment: That directory path is interpreted relative to the _current directory_, which is not necessarily the same directory where the python code is located.  See @tdelaney's comment.

Comment: You'll have to give more information before we can answer this. Likely your current working directory isn't where you want it to be. That would be common when running from a GUI. But until you give us (1) your CWD and (2) how you ran this program, we are at a dead end.